# Do HP switches lock their SFP Ports?

Tags: switch, sfp

Does HP lock the SFP ports on their switches?

I'm looking in particular at an HP E5406zl, but I imagine it's a policy across all their switches or all their switches at a particular level.

We're replacing an existing aging switch with a new model, I'd like to use some SFP units we have on hand that are not HP branded. Before I can commit to this, I need to know: does HP lock their switches to only supported HP-branded/keyed SFP units? This is a $6000 swing in the cost of the upgrade, and can be the difference in whether I'm allowed to do this at all, but before I can move I need to hear something *definitive*.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a definitive answer to this, as it will vary across models. Personally, I can confirm I've used generic gigabit SR SFPs with success in Procurve 5400, 5300 and 2600 series switches. However, a generic 10GbE GBIC in the 5400 failed quite quickly, though that wasn't longer after the 10GB module was released for that switch, so expect the generics might have come along a bit since then. In any case, if you buy generics you won't get any support from HP for them, which might be a bigger consideration.

Comment: @JamesYale my usual strategy is to buy just one pair of name-brand sfps, and if I have a connection issue use them at either end of the link in question for the duration of a support call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pulled back to this today, and now know the correct answer is, "Sort of".

Some HP switches (including my model from the question) **do** have protections on the ports. However, they do **not** fully brand-lock the ports.

In other words, a switch may require an SFP to identify itself from a list of HP product numbers (eg: J4858C), but other brands can and do use those numbers in their SFPs. So not just any generic SFP will work in every HP switch, but you certainly can get generic SFPs that *will* work (and *have* worked well for me now for more than 5 years) for much less than HP charges.

It seems the reason HP does this has as much to do with real quality control as it does vendor lock-in or propping up their SFP pricing. There was a model SFP they produced that was flawed; they released an updated model and later switches and firmwares would reject the original.

Of course, this also speaks to a specific product and point in time. HP policies may have changed, or may be different and more restrictive or less restrictive at different product levels.

Answer (score 3):

I've used non-HP transceivers in 5400zl switches before. Your best bet it to get a small eval or sample and try it in your environment.

I also hope you're not paying retail for those 5406 switches :)

Comment: Perfect. This is a zl model, so that's exactly what I needed to hear.

Comment: I don't have a complete list, but I've used SFP cables as well. But seriously, you'll have to test before committing.